# CMake running fine but build not working for 3rd party library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, dependencies, cpprest-sdk

I need to use OpenSSL and [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) in a C++ project I'm working on but I'm having issues getting it to build properly. In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Final_Project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl)

find_package(cpprestsdk REQUIRED NAMES cpprestsdk cpprest )

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Final_Project main.cpp)
```

Which builds just fine and returns no errors. All my code as of right now is contained in main.cpp.

In main.cpp I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Running!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But whenever I try to build/run it I get an error with cpprest:

```
Scanning dependencies of target Final_Project
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Final_Project.dir/main.cpp.o
/Users/myAccount/myFolder/Final Project/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'cpprest/http_client.h' file not found
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Final_Project.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Final_Project.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed OpenSSL and cpprestsdk with homebrew just fine and I've added everything I think I need to my PATHs. I've tried adding command line arguments to GCC to include the cpprestsdk path and I've tried renaming the `#include <cpprest...> to #include <cpprestsdk...>` but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas? I'm sure it's just something simple I'm missing.

Comment: *I've tried adding command line arguments to GCC to include the cpprestsdk path* -- You should state exactly what you have tried, not just state you've tried different things.  The error is obvious that the compiler cannot resolve `cpprest/http_client.h`.  Maybe you specified the path incorrectly?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried "-I /usr/local/opt/cpprestsdk/" and "-I /usr/local/opt/cpprestsdk/lib/cpprestsdk" and many combinations between that. The first path is a symlink to /usr/local/Cellar/cpprestsdk/2.10.8

Comment: Hi, you can try to print the varialble to check if the path is correct: `message(STATUS "cpprestsdk include dir: ${cpprestsdk_INCLUDE_DIRS}")`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, my project name had a space in it so I refactored it without that and updated my CMake accordingly. I also had to add the target_link_libraries below the add_executable line. Example of my working CMakeLists below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(FinalProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Set OpenSSL dir, this *should* be default on linux/mac
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl)

# Get OpenSSL
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

# Get cppRestSDK
find_package(cpprestsdk REQUIRED)

# Compile + Link
add_executable(FinalProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(FinalProject PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest)
```